# Can someone help my identity this silk painting please

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, traditional-characters, names

[image][image][image][image]Hello I inherited 4 silk Chinese paintings and would love to know who made them and what the red stamps mean? [image]

Comment: It is not legible. Please improve the quality of the image.  Taking a separate, enlarged, shot at the seal may help.

Comment: I don’t know how to add more than 2 photos

Comment: You did just fine. Now someone may come to help out those seals.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Answer (score 2):

執扇如意 - contently holding a fan

輕步欄柵 - walk along railing with light steps

寧立靜思 - tranquility stand and quietly think

芙蓉映波 - beautiful face reflect on the water

- 芙蓉 is a kind of flower, often used in classical literature to represent a beautiful woman's face
- 波 can mean water wave, often used in place of "water" in classical literature

Comment: is there anyway to figure out how old these pictures are, or the artist please?

Comment: And thank you so much for telling me what they say, they are very beautiful pictures